# WP API and React rendering HTML, not text

Tags: wordpress, reactjs

I am creating a react wordpress blog.  Right now I am sending a JSON request and getting all of the posts, this is working properly )  Once I have that I am creating a post object for each post.

I can properly display the title, image, etc.  However when I try to display the content of the post using post.content.rendered ( i take the first 250 characters for a preview ) It is showing the actual html in the output for example instead of printing "Hello World" it is printing

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

I am getting the json response successfully from: /wp-json/wp/v2/posts and i am returning the post info in the code below.

```
return (
    <article className="post-outer" id={post.id}>
      <section className="post-section">
        <a className="post-link">
          <div className="post-box" >
            <h1 className="post-title">
              {post.title.rendered}
            </h1>
            <p className="post-desc">
              {post.content.rendered.substring(0,250)}
            </p>
            </div>
          <figure className="media-wrapper"><img src={ this.state.media } /></figure>
        </a>
      </section>
    </article>
  )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render html strings:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content.rendered }} />
```

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is React's replacement for using `innerHTML` in the browser `DOM`, behind the scenes when you use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` it lets `React` know that the HTML inside of that component is not something it cares about.

Check this example:

```js
let a = "<p>Hello</p>";
let b = "<p>Hello";
let c = "<p>Hello<";
let d = "<p>Hello</";

class App extends React.Component{
   
   render(){
     return(<div>
       <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: a}}></div>
       <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: b}}></div>
       <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: c}}></div>
       <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: d}}></div>
      </div>
     )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: any idea how to only show the first 250 characters of the html output?

Comment: if you using the html string then it should be proper otherwise it will be appear as text. check the attached snippet :)