# Headless Wordpress API: how to remove html in JSON

Tags: html, wordpress, reactjs, api

I'm fetching content from wordpress via their headless api stuff. 
But the text being returned shows html tags I just want the pure text with no html. And how can I then add breaks and make some part of the text bold etc.

This is my code condensed;

```
componentDidMount(){
   const pageURL = "http://localhost:8888/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/5";
   fetch(pageURL)
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(response => {
     this.setState({
       content: response.content.rendered
     });
   })
 }

render() {
let content = this.state.content;
return (
 <div className="AboutUsContainer">
   <div className="Bio">
    <p>{content}</p>
  </div>
 </div>
  )
  }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: I don't know of a WordPress based solution. You could let Javascript strip the tags of the text. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Comment: Anyone who sees this in the future use this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564801/wp-api-and-react-rendering-html-not-text

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you as @ali said,
just use this line instead of yours

```
this.setState({
    content: response.content.rendered.replace(/<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi, '');
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a `str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/gi, '')` for display content. So easy.